Clickhouse - how to transform (pivot) table
I have the following data in Clickhouse



date
value
type
subtype




2021-01-01
1
A
x


2021-01-01
2
A
y


2021-01-01
3
B
x


2021-01-01
4
B
y


2021-01-02
5
A
x


2021-01-02
6
A
y


2021-01-02
7
B
x


2021-01-02
8
B
y



I need to transform it into the following form



date
Ax
Ay
Bx
By




2021-01-01
1
2
3
4


2021-01-02
5
6
7
8



The combinations of Type and Subtype are not known. I made the following query:
SELECT
    date
    , groupArray((type, subtype, value)) agg
FROM my_table
group by date
order by date DESC

but it returns



date
agg




2021-01-01
[(A, x, 1), (A, y, 2), (B, x, 3), (B, y, 4)]


2021-01-02
[(A, x, 5), (A, y, 6), (B, x, 7), (B, y, 8)]



What should I do to transform the agg array into columns?
I achieved what I need using pandas.DataFrame.pivot, but how can I do using SQL only?

Why are you tagging pandas, and not SQL when you are looking for a solution using the latter?

My bad, fixed tags

Several approaches described in https://kb.altinity.com/altinity-kb-queries-and-syntax/pivot-unpivot/
